# Should I turn off copy-on-write for ~/.thunderbird?

Tags: btrfs

Does the mailbox file in .thunderbird considered a database file (repetitively random written)? How bad the fragmentation is if I leave the .thunderbird on a normal BTRFS partition? I hope people can share their experiences on this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

- the mbox format (still) used by default by Thunderbird for mailboxes is sequential – new mail is attached at the end. So, no random write access at all!
- The message metadata (where in the mailbox file does each message start? Is it deleted? any tags?) is stored in what is called a MORK database file (.msf). That's an abysmal database format (which everyone seems to agree on). Changing anything in that requires most of the file to be rewritten (it's something half-sequential). So, no random punctual write access either.
- I don't know how many emails you get, but even on bad days, it's < 2 per minute for me. Not "frequently" in the sense that e.g. your browser's history is frequently written. (which actually is a database file these days – SQLite if you use Firefox, for example)
- COW can be just as efficient as not doing COW even on actual random access modifications. Storage media literally can't change a single byte at a time. They physically have to write back a modified block, including calculation of forward error correction redundancy.

  - So, for flash-based storage (SSDs), a storage-device-sized block COW behaviour has no downsides, since there's no seek time involved with files being fragmented. (As a matter of fact, SSDs *always* do COW internally for blocks, for wear leveling reasons.)
  - For devices with seek times (HDD), of course, fragmented files would be bad for access times when reading sequentially through the file. If that matters to you, you might have very many emails (like me, I counted lately, and my Thunderbirds has > 50,000 emails) and you might need to think about alternatives to Thunderbird (like I do constantly, even though I'm using an SSD array. I never use Thunderbird to do full-text searches anymore locally. My virtual server with much much less performance in CPU, RAM and storage than my workstation keeps a fulltext index for server-side searching and is > 20× as fast as thunderbird, so I [(awkwardly) use](https://superuser.com/questions/1740596/in-thunderbird-how-to-make-quick-filter-body-search-on-server) the "search on server" feature to let my IMAP server search emails instead of thunderbird doing it locally).

All in all: go and worry about other things than the couple of emails you process with your desktop email client! Modern file systems certainly work well enough for that.

(The ugly truth is that Mozilla, literally for the last decade, has been working on replacing the inefficient way it stores messages and message information. Some of the approaches they're choosing currently, but seem to need a while to get production-ready, are great, like using a proper database file for what is currently Mork, others are not so great, such as going for the Maildir format, which isn't really efficient if you need to do any cross-email operations, which is actually where performance starts to matter. I give thunderbird that reworking thunderbird to make use of "normal" file formats for this kind of problem is complex. I also allow myself to be of the opinion that this is a fundamental shortcoming, and we have 4 bad chat messengers in Thunderbird now, some of which aren't even for chat networks that still exist. In contrast, we don't have a robust and reasonably efficient way to store emails – in an email client.)

Comment: Mboxes get rewritten when you delete email ;-). Isn’t some metadata stored as email headers? IIRC when a read receipt is sent, that’s tracked in the mbox with some MUAs, but I’m not sure about Thunderbird.

Comment: @StephenKitt mbox: that's correct, there's a (sparsely running, alos triggerable manually as "compact …") routine that removes the messages that were marked as deleted in the Mork database. But as you say, that's basically "keep everything up to that deleted email, move the range until the next deleted email forward, repeat until end of file", and thus very sequential writing. Pretty good method to defragment the newer emails's backing blocks, actually, thinking about it :)

Comment: Mozilla's .msf/Mork documentation, whilst still relevant, has all to be scraped from archive.org (uhhhh... not great, mozilla), so I gave up at some point trying to figure out what was actually specifically stored in .msf files, other than by reading the code, which I must fully admit I didn't feel I should spend too much time on :)